Understanding Full Nodes and Light Nodes in IOTA DLT + Setting Up a Light Node on Raspberry Pi 4
I'm looking for information about the concepts of full nodes and light nodes in the IOTA Distributed Ledger Technology (DLT). Specifically, I want to know if these concepts exist in IOTA and how I can set up a light node on a Raspberry Pi. My goal is to connect this light node to a local full node running on my PC, such as the Wasp node or hornet node. If there are any tutorials or documentation available, I would greatly appreciate any pointers.
